# Invalid query: Unknown column 'referral_id' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql

Help, This is the full error

> SELECT `id`, `Username`, `IP`, `SecureIP`, `AdminLevel`, `Helper`,
>   `referral_id` FROM `accounts` WHERE `Username` = 'test'Invalid query:
>   Unknown column 'referral_id' in 'field list'

My code

```
$admquery = "SELECT `id`, `Username`, `IP`, `SecureIP`, `AdminLevel`, `Helper`, `referral_id` FROM `accounts` WHERE `Username` = '$myusername'";
$admincheckquery = mysql_query($admquery);

if (!$admincheckquery) {
    echo $admquery;
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

$adminchk = mysql_fetch_array($admincheckquery);
```

HELP

Comment: Well, the error is self-explaining: `Unknown column 'referral_id'`
, i.e. there's no column with that name in that table.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: please execute SELECT * FROM `accounts` and check the names of all columns.

Comment: @sgrillon or, better yet, execute a `SHOW CREATE TABLE accounts` and make note of the columns and their types.

Comment: Downvoting for failing to even try to look at a search engine or read documentation first.

Answer (score 0):

referral_id column doesn't exist in the accounts table.